How to refresh a video scene if/when HSL streaming stops playing?
I have this very simple roku app, with this single video scene to play the live m3u8 stream forever. But eventually then video freezes. Is it possible to detect the video is not playing, destroy and recreate the videocontent ?
<?xml version = "1.0" encoding = "utf-8" ?> 
<component name = "VideoExample" extends = "Scene" >
  <script type = "text/brightscript" >
    <![CDATA[

    sub init()
      videocontent = createObject("RoSGNode", "ContentNode")
      videocontent.live = true
      videocontent.PlayStart = 999999999
      videocontent.streamformat = "hls"
      videocontent.url = "my_m3u8_url"

      video = m.top.findNode("exampleVideo")
      video.content = videocontent

      video.setFocus(true)
      video.control = "play"
    end sub

    ]]>

  </script>
  <children >
    <Video id = "exampleVideo"/>
  </children>
</component>


To track the state of the video and detect if it freezes, you can use the observeField to monitor the state field of the Video node. If the video state indicates an error or stops playing, you can then restart the player with a new content. Here is an updated version of your code with the necessary changes:
<?xml version = "1.0" encoding = "utf-8" ?> 
<component name = "VideoExample" extends = "Scene" >
  <script type = "text/brightscript" >
    <![CDATA[

    sub init()
        videocontent = createObject("RoSGNode", "ContentNode")
        videocontent.live = true
        videocontent.PlayStart = 999999999
        videocontent.streamformat = "hls"
        videocontent.url = "my_m3u8_url"
      
        video = m.top.findNode("exampleVideo")
        video.observeField("state", "onStateChanged")
        video.content = videocontent

        video.setFocus(true)
        video.control = "play"
    end sub

    sub onStateChanged(event as object)
        state = event.getData()
      
        ? "onStateChanged(), state = " state
      
        if (state = "error" or state = "finished")
          restartPlayer()
        end if
      
    end sub
      
    sub restartPlayer()
       ' logic to restart the player with new content
    end sub

    ]]>

  </script>
  <children >
    <Video id = "exampleVideo"/>
  </children>
</component>

Please check Video node documentation for more details about state field and its possible values.
Additionally, you can check the observeField documentation for more information.
Regarding the freezing issue itself, one possible root cause could be video stream expiration. So, you might want to check that as well.
